# Binding Item itself inside list dataTemplate xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I can't find the right syntax to bind directly the item of my list in xaml.

```
<Listview ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
    <Listview.ItemTemplate>
        <CustomUserControl Item={Binding} />
    </Listview.ItemTempalte>
</Listview>
```

this code works fine. But when i want to add a converter to the binding, it displays me a syntax error :

```
<Listview ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
    <Listview.ItemTemplate>
        <CustomUserControl Item={Binding ,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}} />
    </Listview.ItemTempalte>
</Listview>
```

Does anyone know the way to do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: can't imagine that there isn't already an answer to this question on SO...

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so the answer was just

```
{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}
```

without the comma..

Answer (score 0):

I think you use converter in a wrong way. You may try to define your converter as static resource.

```
            <converters:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
```

and use this way

```
<Listview ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
<Listview.ItemTemplate>
    <CustomUserControl Item="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" />
</Listview.ItemTempalte>
```

or

```
<Listview ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
<Listview.ItemTemplate>
    <CustomUserControl Item="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" />
</Listview.ItemTempalte>
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, i use the converter like you. But "RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}" is not working because with this code my converter receive as a parameter my CustomeUserControl, not an Item of Items.

Comment: Sorry, i have misunderstood your problem. Maybe this is the answer <CustomUserControl Item="{Binding /, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" /> *slash char*

Comment: No i tried : "Binding /", "Binding Path=.", it always tells me that "/ property not found" or ". property not found"

Comment: and the logic answer would be "{Binding, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" but it does not compile..